# ReactJS How to prefill with details on other sites form from react component?

Tags: reactjs, forms

I have a requirement of pre-filling form on the website. Once the user clicks a button from React Component, he will be redirected to the website and form will be pre-filled for him.

How can I achieve this? Is it even possible?

Comment: I would say that it's not secure.

Comment: Please, take into account spelling and reread the question before publishing. Sometimes while writing one could fly away with thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how that server is implemented. One page cannot just fill in form fields of a page that it links to. However, if that server accepted request parameters consisting of your username and password, and had some code to use those parameters to set the field values, then you would send that info in the format that server requires.

Without that receiving page directly supporting this use case, you won't be able to do this as you describe.

Comment: some software's for that field, pre-fills forms for users. Not sure about how one website can?